# fluent service API in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've like to expose a fluent service API similar to that on the AngularJS $http API while delegating to it.

Something like:

```
login(user).success(function(data, status) {
    // success case    
}).error(function(data, status) {
    // fail case
}).go();
```

The implementation would actually somehow invoke the AngularJS $http API.

```
$http.post('/api/login', user).success(function(data, status) {
    // success case    
}).error(function(data, status) {
    // fail case
});
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret is as simple as returning `this` for each chainable method call:

```
var MyApi = {
    something : function() {
        console.log('something');
        return this;
    },

    elseIsh : function() {
        console.log('else');
        return this;
    },

    again : function() {
        console.log('again');
        return this;
    }
}

MyApi.something().again().elseIsh().again();
```

And with an initial function call with a new constructor function like this:

```
var does = function() {
    if(this.constructor !== does) {
        return new does();
    }
    console.log('does');
}

does.prototype.something = function() {
    console.log('something');
    return this;
}

does.prototype.elseIsh = function() {
    console.log('else');
    return this;
}

does.prototype.again = function() {
    console.log('again');
    return this;
}

does()​.again().something().elseIsh().again();​
```

Comment: That was easy... just like a builder in any other OO language. I'll go stand in the corner and where my dummy hat for an hour. :-)

Comment: Admitted, determining in JS if the function has been called with `new` or directly is a little tricky.